# How to match regular expression for lines without number?

Tags: regex

I've multiple lines text, and want to match only lines without numbers:

```
text without numbers
text 1 with number

some other text
text without numbers
text 1 with number


text without numbers
text 1 with number
```

I'm out of luck. any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^[^\d]*$
```

Select anything but digits.

Answer (score 5):

You can assert that the whole line consists of nothing but non-numbers:

```
^\D*$
```

`\D` is a shorthand for the character class `[^0-9]` (in current engines hopefully more akin to `[^\d]` with `\d` being Unicode-aware, but I digress ...) which matches everything *but* numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[^0-9]*$/
```

^ = start of line,
[^0-9]* = anything but numbers,
$ = end of line

Comment: This matches lines with numbers. He wants lines with no numbers.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's still morning over here... I edited my original post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can you a non greedy match `[a-z ]*?\r\n`

This will work without you having to split each line out to validate.
The pattern matches any alph or space many times but before a line break

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you:

```
<?php
    $string = "your_string";
    if (preg_match('/.*([0-9]*).*/simU', $string)) {
        echo "String with numbers";
    } else {
        echo "String without numbers";
    }
?>
```